# Wi-Fi not automatically connected

Tags: wireless-networking

My PC is wirelessly connected to the wifi. I am using Windows 10 (20H2), however, it no longer automatically connects when I restart or boot my compmuter. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Go to Windows 10 Settings for Network and then:  Forget the Wireless Setting. (Make sure you know how to reconnect).

Restart the computer.

Now Add the same wireless device and when you do, check the setting that says Always Connect.

This always works for me and the Forget / Restart helps to ensure the succeeding steps will work.

Sometimes just clicking on Always Connect works, but the steps above are better overall.

Comment: I usually first forget the network, then reconnect with setting the always connect flag, and if on a subsequent boot it fails, I then repeat with a reboot in mind. I find that the reboot almost never is necessary.

Comment: I much understand your point but I added the extra step in case for completeness.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand. That's why I gave you the +1 regardless. This is more a comment to more advanced users that are just wondering how mandatory that reboot is.

Comment: @John thank you for your response your answer was very useful for me